# Looking for way of inspecting Drools interactions with Facts

Tags: mockito, drools

I am inserting pojo-like objects/facts into KieSession and have rules that interact with those objects. After all rules are fired I would like to be able to inspect which objects and their methods were accessed by rules. In concept this is similar to mocking.

I attempted to use Mockito and inserted mocked objects into kieSession. I'm able to get a list of methods that were called but not all of the interactions seem to show up.
Not sure if this is Mockito's limitation or it is something about how Drools is managing facts and lifecycles which breaks mocking.

Perhaps there is a better way of accomplishing this?

**Update:** Reasoning - we have an application executing various rule sets. Application makes available all of data but each rule set needs only some subset of the data. There are some monitoring needs where we want to see exactly what data was accessed (getters called on fact objects) by given rule set.

Comment: Why not use listeners? Trying to manually mock out objects is going to get complicated with serialization/deserialization and also you have to really understand the drools lifecycle and how the different phases (eg matching) work.

Comment: It would help if, in addition to describing your attempt, you were to explain _why_ you were trying to do this. Are you trying to approximate code coverage or something out of unit tests? Are you trying to figure out rule hits or something out of production code? etc.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas we have an application executing various rulesets. Application makes available all of data but each ruleset needs only some subset of the data. There are some monitoring needs where we want to see exactly what data was used by given ruleset. Hope this helps.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas looking at the docs I don't see type of events that would give object access information, or am I missing something?

Comment: Create a listener using the provided interfaces. It could be as simple as tracking rule hits -- if you know what rules hit (eg execute), you know what data you use because you have your rule definitions and therefore have a mapping of rule identifier -> data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your question indicates that you (or more likely your management) fundamentally doesn't understand the basic Drools lifecycle:

> Reasoning - we have an application executing various rule sets. Application makes available all of data but each rule set needs only some subset of the data. There are some monitoring needs where we want to see exactly what data was accessed (getters called on fact objects) by given rule set.

The following is a very simplified explanation of how this works. A more detailed explanation would exceed the character limit of the answer field on StackOverflow.

When you call `fireAllRules` in Drools, the rule engine enters a phase called "matching", which is when it decides which rules are actually going to be run. First, the rule engine orders the rules depending on your particular rule set (via salience, natural order, etc.), and then it iterates across this list of rules and executes the left-hand side (LHS; AKA "when clause" or "conditions") only to determine if the rule is valid. On the LHS of each rule, each statement is executed sequentially until any single statement does not evaluate true.

After Drools has inspected all of the rules' LHS, it moves into the "execution" phase. At this point all of the rules which it decided were valid to fire are executed. Using the same ordering from the matching phase, it iterates across each rule and then executes the statements on the right hand side of the rules.

Things get even more complicated when you consider that Drools supports inheritance, so Rule B can extend Rule A, so the statements in Rule A's LHS are going to be executed twice during the matching phase -- once when the engine evaluates whether it can fire Rule B, and also once when the engine evaluates whether it can fire Rule A.

This is *further* complicated by the fact that you can re-enter the matching phase from execution through the use of specific keywords in the right hand side (RHS; aka "then clause" or "consequences") of the rules -- specifically by calling `update`, `insert`, `modify`, `retract`/`delete`, etc. Some of these keywords like `insert` will reevaluate a subset of the rules, while others like `update` will reevaluate all of the words during that second matching phase.

I've focused on the LHS in this discussion because your statement said:

> There are some monitoring needs where we want to see exactly what data was accessed (getters called on fact objects) ....

The majority of your getters should be on your LHS unless you've got some really non-standard rules. This is where you should be getting your data out and doing comparisons/checks/making decisions about whether your rule should be fired.

Hopefully it makes sense as to why the request to know which "get" calls are triggered doesn't really make sense -- because in the matching phase we're going to be triggering a whole lot of "get" calls and then ignoring the result because some other part of the LHS doesn't evaluate true.

---

I did consider that potentially we're having a communication problem here and the actual need is to know what data is actually being used for execution (RHS). In this case, you should be looking to using listeners as I suggested in the comments. If you write a listener that hooks into the Drools lifecycle, specifically onto the execution phase ([AgendaEventListener](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/event/rule/AgendaEventListener.html)'s `afterMatchFired`). At this point, you know that the rule matched and actually was executed, so you can log or record the rule name and details. Since you know the exact data needed and used by each rule, this will allow you to track the data you actually use.

---

This all being said, I found this part concerning based on my previous experience:

> Application makes available all of data but each rule set needs only some subset of the data.

The company I worked for followed this approach -- we made all data available to all the rules by adding *everything* into the working memory. The idea was that if all the data was available, then we would be able to write rules without changing the supporting code because any data that you might need in the future was already available in working memory.

This turned out to be OK when we had small data, but as the company and product grew, this data also grew, and our rules started requiring massive amounts of memory to support working memory (especially as our call volume increased, since we needed that larger heap allocation per rules request.) It was exacerbated by the fact that we were using extremely unperformant objects to pass into working memory -- namely HashMaps and objects which extended HashMap.

Given that, you should *strongly* consider rethinking your strategy. Once we trimmed the data that we were passing into the rules, decreasing both volume and changing the structures to performant POJOs, we not only saw a great decrease in resource usage (heap, primarily) but we also saw a performance improvement in terms of greater rule throughput, since the rule engine didn't need to keep handling and evaluating those massive and inefficient volumes of data in working memory.

---

And, finally, in terms of the question you had about Mocking objects in working memory -- I would strongly caution against attempting to do this. Mocking libraries really shouldn't be used in production code. Most mocking works by leveraging combinations of reflection and bytecode manipulation. Data in working memory isn't guaranteed to remain in the initial state that it was passed in -- it gets serialized and deserialized a different points in the process, so depending on how your specific mocking library is implemented you'll likely lose "access" to the specific mocked instance and instead your rules will be working against a functional equivalent copy from that serialization/deserialization process.

Though I've never tried it in this situation, you may be able to use aspects if you really want to instrument your getter methods. There's a non-negligible chance you'll run into the same issue there, though.

Comment: Appreciate the effort you put into writing this up! This is very insightful and helps me a ton!